# Overload Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, real-time

I am making real time notification for new messages updates using jquery ajax.
The message updates will be requested when user open the page which the javascript code is using window.onload. After the request complete, it will create another new request.
The problem is, when user refresh page or open another page, it will execute new ajax request for the message updates.
After a few refresh page, page become heavy and slow due to a lot of ajax request before that have not completed yet.

So, how to close the previous ajax request so that there will only a request at a time?

Thanks!

Below is just an example code to help you understand what I have asked about.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function request_updates() {
    var curr = $('#current_num').value();
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'ajax/ajax_message_update.php?curr='+curr,
        'type': 'get',
        'success': function(data) {
            var message = 'You have '+data+' new messages!';
            $('#notification-box').html(message);
            request_updates();
        }
    });
}
window.onload = request_updates;
</script>
```

In ajax/ajax_message_update.php

```
<?php
// ajax/ajax_message_update.php
$current_num = $_GET['curr'];
$new_num = $current_num;
while($current_num == $new_num) {
    sleep(5);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=".user_id();
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $new_num = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
echo $new_num;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably cancel ajax requests. IE for example will keep the request running even if you call `.abort();` on your XHR object.

The best you can do is assigning every request an increasing ID and then ignoring any responses from requests with an ID which isn't the one of the most recent request.

On a side-node:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id=".user_id();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$new_num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

is a horrible way to count the rows. Use this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE id=' . user_id());
$new_num = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
```